# Authorize.net Payment integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm looking to do Authorize.net payment integration with a website using PHP.

My questions are:

1) Where I can find a tutorial, development guide, and/or code samples for doing this with PHP.

2) Is it possible to obtain a test account to do the integration like Paypal's sandbox, or does one need to have a live account to which you can pass an additional parameter to indicate the transaction is a test one?

All other advice will also be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) I'm guessing you will be doing an 'AIM' integration (Advanced Integration Method). Authorize.net has [code samples](http://developer.authorize.net/samplecode/) in a few different languages, including PHP. You can also find the [AIM docs](http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/).

2) You can definitely get a test account which will run in test mode, as opposed to production. [Different types of test credit cards](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/authorizenet/) can be used with your test account. <strike>I don't remember if you can sign up for it online or if you need to call and speak with someone.</strike>

In regards to 1, I have no idea how good the sample code is because I've never used it, but I'm guessing it will give you a good idea of what's going on.

EDIT: Let me not forget, I'm guessing that http://developer.authorize.net/ will become your friend if you are going to roll your own implementation. And, you can [sign up for a test account](http://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/) online.

Answer (score 8):

Tutorial
http://www.johnconde.net/blog/tutorial-integrating-the-authorizenet-aim-api-with-php/

Test Account
http://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see some more advanced AIM implementations, you can check out any of the major PHP-based e-commerce systems, like Magento, osCommerce, or zencart.  They all support AIM out of the box, and can be useful.

Of course, as theIV said, Authorize.net's developer guides are pretty good, too.

Comment: That's a pretty good point. You can always take a look at some of the open source projects out there, but unfortunately, some of them are a f'ing mess.